# Creating a new instance/object from a class with nested JSON key value pairs in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, sorting, initialization, nested-lists

I have some JSON that I want to convert to an object but I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort the data and pass it into an initialize method for a class.

I've already used file.read to put my JSON into key/value pairs organised within an array, however the cost attribute is nested as follows

```
      [
        { "restaurant": "hells kitchen", "cost": { "dine in": 100.00 } },
        { "restaurant": "sals pizza", "cost": { "dine in": 25.50, "takeaway": 20.00, "delivery": 28.50 } },
        { "restaurant": "five guys burgers", "cost": { "dine in": 18.50, "takeaway": 16.50, "delivery": 20.00 } }
      ]
```

Ideally I'd like to assign these values and have them accessible as attributes of the instantiated class object like this a rough example.

```
class Restaurant

    attr_accessor :name, :type, :cost

    def initialise(json_data)
    
    #something to sort the data here#
    
    end

end
```

I can't figure out a good way of adding the data to the attributes and would really appreciate any advice on how to retrieve the data and place it into the initialize method.

My apologies in advance if my terminology, explanation or understanding is lacking, I'm very new to Ruby and programming in general.

Thank you!

Comment: I proposed an anwer. You can also first instantiate your class and then manipulate the array in a specific method of that class, rather than manipulating in the initializer.

Comment: Instance variables `:name, :type, :cost` are not consistent with the json structure, for example: `{ "restaurant": "five guys burgers", "cost": { "dine in": 18.50, "takeaway": 16.50, "delivery": 20.00 } }`. Can you review the desired output? - Also `initialise` must be `initialize`.

Comment: Effectively I wanted to try put multiple eating types and associated costs under the same model, with the variables as a way to access them later after they've been created. 

Is that possible or would it not work because of the multiple values for eating types(dine in, takeaway etc) and their cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better put the parsing code out the `Restaurant` class like this:

```rb
class Restaurant
  attr_accessor :name, :type, :cost

  def initialize(name, type, cost)
    @name, @type, @cost = name, type, cost  
  end
end

restaurants = json_data.flat_map do |hash|
  name = hash[:restaurant]

  hash[:cost].map do |type, cost|
    Restaurant.new(name, type, cost)
  end
end

# Then you can use:
r = restaurants.first
r.name
r.type
r.cost
```

---

Update based on comment:

```rb
class Restaurant
  attr_accessor :name, :costs

  def initialize(name, costs)
    @name, @costs = name, costs
  end

  def types
    @costs.keys
  end
end

restaurants = json_data.map do |hash|
  Restaurant.new(hash[:restaurant], hash[:cost])
end

# Then you can use:
r = restaurants.first
types = r.types
type1 = types.first
cost1 = r.costs[type1]
```

Comment: Hey thanks heaps! this is super helpful. 

However I'm running into an issue because each restaurant has multiple eating types and costs associated with them. How would I build those into the class when it only takes one of each in the arguments to initialize?

Is there any way I could say, build the attributes to be associated so I could have multiple eating types and costs on a single restaurant name?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Danzai Check out update part to see if that fit your need. If not then what do you want to achieve, could you give a example?

Comment: Perfect!! That works exactly how I needed. The important thing was how to store all the values in the attribute and then access them by a method. The "type" method here is just what I was looking for.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The json is an array of hashes.

```
abc = [
        { "restaurant": "hells kitchen", "cost": { "dine in": 100.00 } },
        { "restaurant": "sals pizza", "cost": { "dine in": 25.50, "takeaway": 20.00, "delivery": 28.50 } },
        { "restaurant": "five guys burgers", "cost": { "dine in": 18.50, "takeaway": 16.50, "delivery": 20.00 } }
      ]

irb(main):008:0> abc
=> [{:restaurant=>"hells kitchen", :cost=>{:"dine in"=>100.0}}, {:restaurant=>"sals pizza", :cost=>{:"dine in"=>25.5, :takeaway=>20.0, :delivery=>28.5}}, {:restaurant=>"five guys burgers", :cost=>{:"dine in"=>18.5, :takeaway=>16.5, :delivery=>20.0}}]
```

Thus you can manipulate that directly

```
irb(main):009:0> abc[0]
=> {:restaurant=>"hells kitchen", :cost=>{:"dine in"=>100.0}}
```

I don't know what exactly you want to do but all [array methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html) are directly available : `map`, `each`,...

Within the initialize method, you can manipulate the data and set your class variable and method variables. `attr_reader` is sufficient if you set the variables in the initialize method.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Super helpful I'll try working with the array methods.

Though what I'm trying to achieve, is instances of the class with one restaurant name, under which I could have multiple eating types with their associated cost, is that possible using attr_accessor/reader?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With pleasure @Danzai. If this is helpful, please click the up-arrow and/or mark this a solution.